# Method for determining if a string is a valid variable name

Tags: ruby

Is there a method I can call that would return true if a string is a valid variable name and false otherwise?

I noticed that instance_variable_get internally uses rb_is_instance_id, but I couldn't find that method exposed for me to call.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Agreed, sounds like you may want to give [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx) a read.

Comment: It's a common needs in meta programming

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type of variable you are talking about.  This function will tell you whether a string is a valid instance variable name.  Ruby may have different rules for different types of variables.

```
def valid_variable_name?(var_name)
  Object.new.instance_variable_set ('@'+var_name).to_sym, nil
  true
rescue NameError
  false
end


puts valid_variable_name?('banana') # => true
puts valid_variable_name?("\x00")   # => false
puts valid_variable_name?('#')      # => false
puts valid_variable_name?(':')      # => false
puts valid_variable_name?('@')      # => false
puts valid_variable_name?('/')      # => false
```

Comment: I like this idea.  Let the ruby to decided whether the string is a valid name or not.  Same principle can be used for other stuff like class name, file name, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need. And I would also suggest to check if var_name is nil. It's important when mass importing.

Answer (score 1):

```
!!(defined?(string).to_s =~ /variable/)
```